# How does Life Honing affect weapons with attacks that have multiple hits?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

Once you upgrade a weapon to the point where you can't upgrade it any further and it's rarity 8 or above, you will gain the ability to [hone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_ws-blS8yc) the weapon, either adding increased attack power, defense (and a hidden Divine Blessing), or life (which sometimes heals you when you attack).

The amount of health restored through a life hone depends on the motion value of the attack. Weak attacks heal less than strong ones - for example, most attacks by Dual Blades will heal for around a Herb or Potion's worth, whereas a level 3 Great Sword charge will heal more than half of your maximum health!

But how does the life honing work with attacks that hit multiple times, such as a Charge Blade's ultra discharge (which hits 3 times + the number of explosions) or most of a Bow's attacks (almost all of them hit multiple times)? Does it only "proc" on a single part of those attacks or does it use the whole thing? Is the amount healed based on one of these parts or does it take the whole attack into account?

Comment: I am not that advanced in the game, have lots of work to do, but as an MH Veteran I am certain that the charge blade discharge explosions wont be affected by the life honing as like attack didn't empower gunlances wyvernfire attack

Comment: @xerido The CB's ultra discharge still has multiple "hits" even if we ignore the explosions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some talk and research.

Life honing has an internal cooldown of aproximately 5 seconds, to avoid multiple activations in multiple hits by a multihit atack or multiple attacks in a short spawn.

Taking this into account after some testing it seems it only takes into account the first hit that activates this honing, in the case of a bow it would be a low healing and in case of a chargeblade it would depend of the first hit on the Monster

Sources: Felow trusted hunters testings and gaijin hunter video

[Gaijin Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_ws-blS8yc)